# Laravel Cashier - How to execute a function once when subscription is over?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm using Cashier on my laravel application. It has a simple way of verifying if the user is subscribed:

```
$user->subscribed();
```

Cashier stores on the users table a field "stripe_active" to check if the user has an active subscription. Now, I'm trying to do something kinda simple, but didn't find in the documentation.

When the user subscription expires, I want to run a function that will disable some stuff on the user account and save it to the database. I don't want to check and run it at every login , I want it to fire only once, when the account expires.

So I looked into Cashier's StripeGateway file, which has this function :

```
public function cancel($atPeriodEnd = true)
{
    $customer = $this->getStripeCustomer();

    if ($customer->subscription) {
        if ($atPeriodEnd) {
            $this->billable->setSubscriptionEndDate(
                Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->getSubscriptionEndTimestamp($customer))
            );
        }

        $customer->cancelSubscription(['at_period_end' => $atPeriodEnd]);
    }

    if ($atPeriodEnd) {
        $this->billable->setStripeIsActive(false)->saveBillableInstance();
    } else {
        $this->billable->setSubscriptionEndDate(Carbon::now());

        $this->billable->deactivateStripe()->saveBillableInstance();
    }
}
```

Now it appears that when the account is canceled, two functions run - cancelSubscription and deactivateStripe. I didn't find a documented way to run something on account expire, so I figured I might have to extend these methods and run it myself, but I'm a bit lost on how to do it.  Can someone help out?